# Is it possible to use the string value of an array element as a variable name?

Tags: arrays

Good day, I have seen some of the answers, and they don't really fit what I'm trying to accomplish.

Say I have a 2D array (filled from a csv file) with rows like :-

```
'Sun', 1,2,3
'Mercury', 2,3,4
'Venus', 3,4,5 ....etc
```

Let's call the array `"planet"`

What I'm trying to do id to assign the first body in planet to a sphere e.g.

```
for i in range(0,3,1):
    planet[i] = sphere(pos=vector(planet[i][1], planet[i][2], planet[i][3])
```

Get my drift ?

Comment: You mean you want a JSON?

`{
"venus": sphere(pos=vector(planet[i][1], planet[i][2], planet[i][3]),
...
}
`

Comment: Well I don't know what a JSON is, but, yes, instead of specifically stating "venus", I want to use "planet[i]".

Comment: Check it out: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Python 2.7.14, will this Java work in Python ?

Comment: OK, I've managed to get this working now, without using C and/or JSON :)